# vb.net DrawArc won't refresh in Picturebox

Tags: vb.net, drawing, picturebox

I am trying to show an animated arc being drawn in a picture box. I can't get the arc to paint at each loop (every 100 degrees). The paint triggers only at the end of the sub routine with the final arc at 300 degrees. How can I force a refresh of the picture box during each loop? Here is my code and form.

```
 Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint

    Dim pen As New Pen(Color.Red, 1)
    Dim r As Integer = 100

    'Delay(2)

    Do Until r > 300
        e.Graphics.DrawArc(pen, 50, 50, 50, 50, 270, r)           ' pen style, x position, y postion, width, height, start point degrees, arc degrees
        ListBox1.Items.Add(r)
        ListBox1.SelectedIndex = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        r = r + 100
        Delay(1)
    Loop

    e.Dispose()
    pen.Dispose()
    ListBox1.Items.Add("Done")

End Sub
```

[image]

I've tried using picturebox1.refresh(), update(), invalidate() within the loop without success.

Comment: You could try putting `Application.DoEvents();` just before the end of your `Loop`

Comment: DoEvents didn't work

Comment: The problem is that you are using e.Graphics. This is not processes until after the code that raised the `Paint` event has returned. Not sure, but if you got the `Graphics` from the form instead, it might work like you expect.

Comment: You are correct, functionality works at the form level. However, I plan to do fast repaints and don't want to repaint my entire form. I see some flickering of the graphic at the form level. I was hoping to just repaint the picture box to minimize flickering and faster repaints of graphic.

Comment: PictureBox is double-buffered, you will not see the result until your Paint event handler returns.  Never, *never* hang a Paint event, ever.  Use a Timer instead, call Invalidate() in the Tick event handler to force a repaint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you use a timer instead?

```
Imports System.Timers.Timer

Public Class Form1
Dim tmr1 As New Timer
Dim r As Int32 = 0

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Me.DoubleBuffered = True

    AddHandler tmr1.Tick, AddressOf tmr1_Tick
    With tmr1
        .Interval = 1000
        .Start()
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub tmr1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If r < 300 Then
        r += 100
        ListBox1.Items.Add(r)
        ListBox1.SelectedIndex = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        Me.PictureBox1.Invalidate()
    Else
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Done")
        tmr1.Stop()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    Dim pen As New Pen(Color.Red, 1)
    Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
    Debug.WriteLine("PictureBox1: " & r)
    g.DrawArc(pen, 50, 50, 50, 50, 270, r)           ' pen style, x position, y postion, width, height, start point degrees, arc degrees

    pen.Dispose()
End Sub
End Class
```